# angular.js app with linked panels

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am learning Angular and i am ok with the basics however i have a situation where i have 3 interlinking panels or panes. You select the category from the first pane, it populates a list of products in the second pane then choosing one of these populates the third pane with the product details.

I have mocked up the structure here: https://jsfiddle.net/pbpxexsa/1/

Whats the best approach for constructing this?

I added some routing to have a meaningfull url, but i can only have one ng-view.

I have looked at ui.router and this looks like it might fit

Could i just have a separate controller on each pane and an observer to watch for changes but i have read this is to be avoided.

I like the aspect of directives and understand i could provide `<product-pane></product-pane>` and `<product-details></product-details>` directives but again not sure how to link them.

The books i am reading don't seem to cover this kind of architecture, am i missing something obvious?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Very simple - Use [ui.router](http://angular-ui.github.io/ui-router/site/#/api/ui.router) instead to basic angularjs routing and start by reading the [guide](https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/wiki)

Answer (score 0):

I think you might be over-thinking this slightly.  You have 3 panels which are all viewing a single data group, but you are trying to engineer a solution that would only be necessary when each panel is showing different data.  You can *easily* do this design with a single controller.

Just a generic mockup (not working or tested, but should give you an idea):

```
<div class="category-pane">
<ul>
  <li ng-repeat="category in categories" 
      ng-click="setSelectedCategory(category)">{{category.name}}</li>
</ul>
</div>

<div class="products-pane">
<ul>
  <li ng-repeat="product in selectedCategory.products"
      ng-click="setSelectedProduct(product)">{{product.name}}</li>
</ul>
</div>

<div class="product-details-pane>
  {{selectedProduct.name}}
  {{selectedProduct.info}}
  ....
</div>
```

In controller:

```
$scope.setSelectedCategory= function(category){
  $scope.selectedCategory = category;
  $scope.selectedProduct = null;  //remove whatever was in the product pane
};

$scope.setSelectedProduct= function(product){
  $scope.selectedProduct = product;
};
```